# How to erase using feature(s) within the same feature class?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, arcgis-engine, erase

I develop an application and I want to erase overlay features in a feature class in the application. I use ArcEngine 10. I don't have another layer that have erase features then I can't use erase tool in overlay toolset. How to erase using feature(s) within the same feature class? is there any tools or programmatically way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What data type (point, line, polygon, etc) is this feature class?

Comment: @Paul . the data type is polygon

Comment: Have you tried exporting the features you want to use as "erasers" to a new feature class and then use both as input?

Comment: No , I can't do this, because  i develope an application and i have to do this in my application.

Comment: Your question makes no mention of an application - can you please update it to provide potential answerers with details of that key restriction?  Also, it sounds like your question should be "How to erase using feature(s) within the same feature class?".

Comment: When you say that ' i develope an application and i have to do this in my application' do you mean that you need a programmatical (i.e. ArcObjects) way of doing this?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe yes,i need a programmatical way of doing this.If i find a tool or command that do this, i'l find the programmatical way

Comment: I could do this example programmatically using Python but I am still unclear on what you are using as your programming language.  Also, how are you planning to flag your erasing features?  And what happens when you have stacked erasing features?  Will you set an order value too?

Comment: @wetland: You need to provide more information about what you are doing. What Language/API are you using? what have you tried so far? things like that.

Comment: @PolyGeo I use c# language but i can use python codes . could you please help me How can i do this using python ?